# writing an acpi driver in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, acpi

I need to write a kernel module that uses an acpi method to communicate to a hardware device.

At this point I just want to load the driver and enumerate the devices on the bus.

I found a fairly old but reasonable example on line, below is the basic outline. I pretty much took the example verbatim just changing names, I used acpidump to find the dsdt table get the correct device ID etc.

The driver loads fine, but my add functions are not being called.  My suspicion is that I am missing a step to stimulate scanning the bus after I register it. The example assumes the driver is loaded on boot. Is there a way to request the bus be scanned after registering it such that any devices attached to a registered bus will be added? Understand that my suspicion may be wrong so if my assumptions are wrong please correct me.

below is the source:

```
static int viking_acpi_add(struct acpi_device *device);
static int viking_acpi_remove(struct acpi_device *device);
static void viking_acpi_notify(struct acpi_device *adev, u32 event);

static const struct acpi_device_id nv_device_ids[] = {
    { "ACPI0012", 0},
    { "", 0},
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(acpi, nv_device_ids);

static struct acpi_driver nv_acpi_driver = {
    .name =         "NV NVDR",
    .class =        "NV",
    .ids =          nv_device_ids,
    .ops =          {
                            .add =          nv_acpi_add,
                            .remove =       nv_acpi_remove,
                            .notify =       nv_acpi_notify,
                    },
.owner =    THIS_MODULE,
};

//static struct acpi_device acpi_dev;

static int nv_acpi_add(struct acpi_device *device)
{
    printk("NV: acpi bus add\n");
    return 0;
}

static int nv_remove(struct acpi_device *device)
{
    printk("NV: acpi bus remove\n");
    return 0;
}

static void nv_acpi_notify(struct acpi_device *adev, u32 event)
{
    device_lock(&adev->dev);
    printk("notification detected\n");
    device_unlock(&adev->dev);
}

static int __init nv_init(void)
{
    int result = 0;

    result = acpi_bus_register_driver(&nvt_driver);
    if (result < 0) {
        printk("Error registering driver\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit nv_exit(void)
{
    acpi_bus_unregister_driver(&nv_driver);
}

module_init(nv_init);
module_exit(nv_exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that another acpi bus driver was registered for the acpi device ID I was using and the kernel did not call my add routine as a consequence.  When I ran it with a different kernel, my add routine was called as expected.

Comment: So, it means in "non-working" kernel you don't need anything to do. Or you would rather find and hack existing driver.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the statement.  The kernel was working fine.  I was not "hacking" anything.  It is not unusual for the need to write a custom driver for specific hardware in a case where the generic one may not have all the required capabilities.  This being my first driver that used calls to the acpi driver, I was unaware that multiple drivers could not be registered to the same device ID.  Once I realized that, I was able to continue using an earlier kernel.

Comment: That's my point: if the driver exists but doesn't fully serve your purposes there is no need to create a custom driver. Just hack an existing one. It might be also that something you are doing is usually solved by another means.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate your comment. in my experience registering a driver typically adds the driver to a linked list or some other mechanism.  Which enables layered device architecture (filter drivers etc.).  I made a mistake in my assumption and I wanted to clarify why the driver I had written was not being called.